# Java looping through a map and starting a thread depending on a given condition

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have JFrame with two JTables containing different ingredients and dishes. Another class that I've made is a KitchenStaff class that is a thread and uses the required ingredients for the recipe of each dish whenever there are enough ingredients in stock to satisfy the recipe. I also have another class Drone that updates the stock level of ingredients. The problem is that when I start more than one thread and there are at least 2 ingredients that need restocking both threads restock the first ingredient only. Even when they finish they do not bother restocking the other one. Are there any errors in my code and how can I make the threads operate on different ingredients.

```
  @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (this.employed)
            {
                if (!dishStock.getDishStock().isEmpty())
                {

                    for (Map.Entry<SushiDish, Integer> dishEntry : dishStock.getDishStock().entrySet()) {
                        SushiDish dish = dishEntry.getKey();

                        int restockLevel = dishEntry.getValue();

                        if (isDishUnderStock(dish) && areIngredientsEnough(dish))
                        {

                            //int prepTime = new Random().nextInt(41) + 20;
                            int prepTime = 3;
                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(prepTime * 1000);

                                for (Map.Entry<Ingredient, Integer> ingEntry : dish.getRecipe().entrySet())
                                {

                                    Ingredient ingr = ingEntry.getKey();

                                    int quantity = ingEntry.getValue();

                                    ingrStock.useIngredient(ingr, quantity);

                                    for(int i = 0; i < ingrStock.getIngredientsInStock().size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        if (ingrTable.getValueAt(i,0).toString().equals(ingr.getName()))
                                        {
                                            ingrTable.setValueAt(ingrStock.getIngredientsInStock().get(ingr), i, 3);
                                            model.fireTableDataChanged();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you should iterate on the main thread and start a new thread for every ingredient

Comment: then you should very obviously change your title as it says: `starting a thread depending on a given condition`. and for which reason have they be started manually?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer No problem I will find a way on my own as usual.